# Setting up Ditaa in Org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, microsoft-windows, java, cygwin

I've been having trouble setting up ditaa to work in emacs,
I got my copy of the ditaa jar from [here](http://ditaa.sourceforge.net/)
And I've been trying to run this code block

```
#+begin_src ditaa :file hello.png :exports results 
  +----------------+
  | Hello World!!! |
  |                |
  +----------------+

#+end_src
```

When I evaluate it with C-c C-c I  get
A blank png buffer and this:

```
 Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/nalis/emacs-custom-packages/ditaa/ditaa.jar
```

in a buffer called *Shell Command Output*

I've tried moving the jar files to shorter names, putting their location in my system path, and running ditaa outside of emacs to my success.

My Current configurations for my org group are:

```
Org Ditaa Jar Path: ~/emacs-custom-packages/ditaa/ditaa.jar
Org Babel Ditaa Java Cmd: java
Org Ditaa Jar Option: -jar
```

And I am running:
GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.14.13) of 2015-06-23 on desktop-new

Comment: Since this is on Windows, I think I remember there was an issue with "trusting" files that were downloaded from the internet. Could it possibly be something like that? I think that in the file properties (something that should be accessible from the context menu in explorer) on the first tab it'd say something about downloading files from the internet and have a checkbox you need to tick / untick. Also, is this Java installed through Cigwin, or is this a Windows Java? If it is the later, did you try giving it the Windows-y path instead?

Comment: I had @melioratus take a look at it, and he said something along those lines about it being a permissions problem.  As for my java installation it was done in windows, and the windows-y paths all net the same problem. But I'll take a look at the jar files themselves.

Comment: @wvxvw You're right! I had to unblock them in properties, now I can call them as long as I am above the jar files in cmd and minty, so that's part of the problem thanks!

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this**

1. Find full directory path where emacs expects ditaa.jar to be located.

   This code is copied from ob-ditaa.el

   ```
   #+begin_src elisp
   (expand-file-name
                "ditaa.jar"
         (file-name-as-directory
               (expand-file-name
                   "scripts"
                  (file-name-as-directory
                     (expand-file-name
                         "../contrib"
                        (file-name-directory (org-find-library-dir "org")))))))
   #+end_src
   ```

   > **Note:** This path in your setup may be different, so you should run the code above to check then adjust the instructions to meet your specific path.

   ```
   #+RESULTS:
   : /usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/contrib/scripts/ditaa.jar
   ```
2. Copy `ditaa.jar` and `DitaaEps.jar` into expected directory, e.g. `/usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/contrib/scripts`
3. **Windows specific step** - Confirm that `ditaa.jar` and `DitaaEps.jar` are unblocked otherwise Windows OS will block execution.
4. **Cygwin specific step** - Create `call-ditaa.sh` wrapper script.

   > **Note:** The Oracle JSE for Windows expects Windows paths not Cygwin paths, so we needed to convert using `cygpath` command.

   ```
   #+begin_src sh :tangle yes :shebang #!/usr/bin/env bash

       #
       # Convert to windows file paths.
       #

       java $1 $2 "$(cygpath -w $3)" "$(cygpath -w $4)" "$(cygpath -w $5)"


   #+end_src
   ```
5. **Cygwin specific Step** - Customize org-mode to use wrapper script instead calling java directly.

   > **Note:** I suggest putting `call-ditaa.sh` script in same directory as `ditaa.jar`.

   ```
   Org Babel Ditaa Java Cmd: /usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/contrib/scripts/call-ditaa.sh
   ```
6. Customize org-mode to `Org Ditaa Jar Path` to expected path, e.g. `/usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/contrib/scripts/ditaa.jar`
7. Apply & Save customization
8. Test Updated `ditaa` Settings

   ```
   #+begin_src ditaa :file ./helloworld.png
   +----------------+
   | Hello World!!! |
   |                |
   +----------------+
   #+end_src

   #+RESULTS:
   [[file:./helloworld.png]]
   ```

Comment: When I save in org-mode, it removes the trailing whitespace off each line. This breaks my diagram. any ideas on how one might mitigate that issue?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  It works on my cygwin system -- mostly.  The problem is that when I call ditaa with :cmdline options, they get mixed in after $3 but before the last two.  Am working on modifying your script to take that possibility into account.

Answer (score 8):

I am afraid that moving files manually will mess up my system, confuse my package manager and only work until the next update.  Instead, you can simply added the true path for `ditaa.jar` to your `.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el`.  In my case:

```
(setq org-ditaa-jar-path "/usr/share/ditaa/lib/ditaa.jar")
```

Comment: I can't speak for a windows setup but this is definitely the better answer on Linux.

Comment: ... or using `describe-variable org-ditaa-jar-path`, updating and saving it.

Answer (score 1):

Base on Melioratus answer I did this:

```
 cd .emacs.d/elpa && mkdir contrib
 cd contrib %% mkdir scripts
 cd scripts
 which ditaa   ## I have mine in /usr/local/bin
 ln -s /usr/local/bin/ditaa0_9.jar ditaa.jar
 ln -s /usr/local/bin/DitaaEps.jar DitaaEps.jar
```

Now emacs/ org-babel can find ditaa, success!

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried moving the jar files to ... my system path

try lib path instead, or run this command at a terminal prompt to see if ditaa runs on your system without errors:

```
java -jar ditaaXXX.jar
```

adjust the path to the jar file, where xxx is the version number. If installed properly, you'd get the help screen for command line options.

Comment: Okay, I moved ditaa.jar to my /lib/ directory, and renamed it ditaa0_9.jar when I call it in bash I get the same error, but when I use cd to move to lib then it works.

Comment: try fixing lib path to properly recognize that /dir/

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @Melioratus's excellent and comprehensive answer: there remains a problem on my cygwin system when I call ditaa with command line options, as in:

```
#+begin_src ditaa :file images/test_ditaa.png :cmdline -r -s 1.2
```

In that case, when I replace the body of call-ditaa.sh with

```
i=1;
j=$#;
while [ $i -le $j ] 
do
    echo "$i: $1";
    i=$((i + 1));
    shift 1;
done
```

I get *Shell Command Output*

```
1: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2: -jar
3: /usr/local/share/ditaa/lib/ditaa.jar
4: -r
5: -s
6: 1.2
7: /cygdrive/c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/babel-QIscl8/ditaa-xxpRQl
8: /cygdrive/c/Users/me/Downloads/images/test_ditaa.png
```

The extra command line options have wedged themselves inconveniently in the middle of the command line.

Here is my modified call-ditaa.sh script.  It edits the command line in two steps, once for the third argument and once for the last two, then calls java.  It seems to work well for me.

```
set -- "${@:1:2}" "$(cygpath -w $3)" "${@:4}"
set -- "${@: 1:$#-2}" "$(cygpath -w ${@: -2:1})" "$(cygpath -w ${@: -1:1})"
java "$@"
```